# How to convert a (x, y) position to an angle in PHP?

Tags: php

Using PHP 7.3,

I have the position of a point with X-Y coordinates that I need to convert to an angle from 0 to 360.

Assuming (123, 0) is angle 0, (0, 123) is angle 90, (-123, 0) is angle 180, etc.

Is there some function to do that ?

Thx.

Comment: This is where you need trig. 180 * atan2($float_y, $float_x)/M_PI

Comment: I'm not sure this is really much of a PHP problem as a general math problem.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote that:

```
$angle = 180 * atan2($y, $x) / M_PI;
if($angle < 0) {
  $angle += 360;
}
```